# ASP.NET Core and swagger handling of null/missing vlaues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am working in C# with ASP.NET Core. I've created a type like this:

```
public record Person([Required] string email, string? firstName, string? lastName);
```

Then I created a controller function that uses it:

```cs
[Controller]
public class Api
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool CheckPerson([FromBody] Person blah)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I have two problems with this to do with nulls/optional which may be related

- nowhere in the generated swagger definition does it reflect that certain parameters are optional
- for the optional parameters - providing null works, but missing values don't

For example - this works:

```json
{ "email": "a@b.com", "firstName": null, "lastName": null }
```

but this doesn't - doesn't even make it into my function:

```json
{ "email": "a@b.com" }
```

**My question**: how do I make variables that are truly optional - ie I can see in Swagger that they are optional, and I don't have to provide them for the thing to correctly serialize?

Comment: Are you wanting open api 3.x or swagger/oas2?

Comment: I'm using this: app.UseSwagger( options => options.SerializeAsV2 = true); - to get swagger version 2 - tools we use that consume it don't understand v3

Comment: So do you only want to keep rquired `email` and rest of the property retain optional right?

Comment: well - this is only an example - in reality there are _many_ properties - but the principle remains the same - so _yes_